# TRY .. CATCH sometimes fails to catch PRIMARY KEY VIOLATION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure

I wrote code to upsert records to the database. The database is Azure DB, S4 tier.

Updates and inserts are sometimes are highly concurrent since it's coming from the application that doing too many updates.

The code works successfully most of the times, but sometimes it throws 2627 exception (that handled inside of the CATCH statement). Cannot figure out so far what could be the issue.

I can replace it with MERGE statement, but I tbh don't favor it much, and also want to figure out what's happening with this try and catch.

```sql
SET nocount ON;
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @ID)
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO Table(ID, Value, TimeChanged) VALUES (@id, 'xxx', GETDATE())
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@Error <> 2627 ----Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
THROW;
END CATCH

UPDATE MyTable SET Value = 'xxx' WHERE ID = @ID AND TimeChanged < GETDATE()
```

Comment: My theories are
1) add XACT_ABORT ON
2) Add ; before THROW

I could add both and release to prod, but then I wont know what was the issue. And I can't release too often either.

Comment: Is it possible that more than one error is being raised? Could the order of the errors be affecting the @@ERROR value?

Comment: According tho the syntax you have written, I think you want to ignore primary key violation for that particular script. Am I right?

Comment: Rajesh, yes. I expect multiple events at the same time for the same record coming, that's why I dont want  blindly rely on IF NOT EXISTS condition.
There are many ways to rewrite the code to get rid of the issue, but I am curious what exactly the issue is and why try and catch failing (sometimes), but often enough for us to see the exception in prod.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is the issue, but you should use [ERROR_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) not @@error in your catch block.

@@error only returns the error number in the statement immediately following the one that causes an error. While in the catch statement, `ERROR_NUMBER()` will always give the error that threw the exception.

In any case something like this should work reliably, without PK violations:

```
SET nocount ON;
begin transaction
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable with (updlock, holdlock) WHERE ID = @ID)
begin
  INSERT INTO Table(ID, Value, TimeChanged) VALUES (@id, 'xxx', GETDATE())
END 
else
begin
  UPDATE MyTable SET Value = 'xxx' WHERE ID = @ID AND TimeChanged < GETDATE()
end
commit transaction
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to find a difference between those two and I couldn't. Why don't you like @Error?

Answer (score 0):

Better because if the row exists, it only hits the db once.

begin transaction

UPDATE MyTable SET Value = 'xxx' WHERE ID = @ID AND TimeChanged < GETDATE()

if @@rowcount = 0
INSERT INTO Table(ID, Value, TimeChanged) VALUES (@id, 'xxx', GETDATE())

commit transaction